# How to take care of self-signed certificate error?

Tags: certificates, email-spoofing

I'm a newbie to computer security. As part of an assignment, I'm supposed to send an email to a given email id 'E' which is stored at a mail server 'S'. I've tried initiating a telnet session on port 25 with server S but I've been denied permission every single time.

The next thing I tried was initiating a telnet session on port 587, which worked. I then began my attempt to send a spoofed-email, but the command prompt asked me to start a TLS connection using 'starttls'. I read that you must use 'openssl' to establish a connection with the server (S). I followed some instructions online and was able to connect to the server using the 'openssl' command.

When I type "`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect cs2107.spro.ink:25`", I get the following error:

```
OpenSSL> s_client -starttls smtp -connect cs2107.spro.ink:25
CONNECTED(00000200)
depth=0 CN = 8089fe031125
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = 8089fe031125
verify return:1
```

How do I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see the message as it currently is too broad since it does not restrict itself to the specific problem with s_client but broadly asks how to spoof mail. As for your specific problem: s_client will simply ignore these errors and will continue with the handshake. At the end you will get the message from the SMTP server and should continue with the SMTP dialog then. See https://pastebin.com/mTguvt0J

Comment: @SteffenUllrich s_client seems to ignore the errors, but I'm not able to resume my mail spoofing. When I type the recipient address, I get the same error as the one I mentioned above. If I ignore the error and try typing DATA, I get the error of "no valid recipients".. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: I have no idea what for errors you get exactly but based on your description it seems to be at the level of SMTP not TLS. Since you access port 587 instead of 25 it probably also expects you to authorize. I recommend to study how SMTP works first and how to interpret the replies from the server. If you then have a specific problem apart from the broad "how to spoof" then ask a new question with enough details.